# Error compiling async-executor with "cargo build-sbf"

Tags: build-bpf

I got this:

> abcdedf@WudeMacBook-Pro golana % cargo -V
> cargo 1.63.0 (fd9c4297c 2022-07-01)
> abcdedf@WudeMacBook-Pro golana % solana -V
> solana-cli 1.11.10 (src:843e018c; feat:4253057308)
> abcdedf@WudeMacBook-Pro golana % cargo-build-sbf
> Compiling serde_json v1.0.85
> Compiling bv v0.11.1
> Compiling serde_bytes v0.11.7
> Compiling bincode v1.3.3
> Compiling async-executor v1.4.1
> Compiling borsh v0.9.3
> error: could not compile `async-executor`

> Caused by:
> process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name async_executor --edition=2018 /Users/abcdedf/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/async-executor-1.4.1/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=4508878397a6a0c8 -C extra-filename=-4508878397a6a0c8 --out-dir /Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps --target sbf-solana-solana -L dependency=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps -L dependency=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/release/deps --extern async_task=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libasync_task-cd25de3b9964548c.rmeta --extern concurrent_queue=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libconcurrent_queue-71a26d81ebffa4a7.rmeta --extern fastrand=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libfastrand-ca9d3379698c13c6.rmeta --extern futures_lite=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libfutures_lite-9b8259018929f529.rmeta --extern once_cell=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libonce_cell-6f8bb2d96ae5dca1.rmeta --extern slab=/Users/abcdedf/code/github/golana/target/sbf-solana-solana/release/deps/libslab-21ce844d26970987.rmeta --cap-lints allow -Zremap-cwd-prefix=` (signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference)

Hardware: m1 macbook pro

Does this mean the compiler crashed?

async-executor: https://github.com/smol-rs/async-executor

---

update: I think I tracked down the cause: any async function would crash the compiler. Is async-await not supported at all?

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems building that crate using solana's build tools. Good trouble shooting steps would be to run `cargo clean`, reinstalling solana's build tools, and reinstalling rust.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work.
I make a simple test project with the sysvar example by adding async-executor as the only extra dependency, it still crashes.